# How can I set downloaded image as background in activity?

Tags: java, android, background, imageview

I get image from backend into variable ImageView and wish to set this image (which not in resourse files) as background in activity. I surf in internet, but found only variant with resource (drawable). But I have dinamic image.

Java:

```
public class CoreTest extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.core_test);
...
        Imageview imageView;
        Picasso.get().load(GET_IMAGE_URL + testCountry.imageName).into(imageView);
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/core_test"
    tools:context=".CoreTest">
...
```

Comment: What's the problem in your XML to set a full screen background image and download image there?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download image from URL and that downloaded file use to set background of the activity. Make sure to replace "https://www.example.com/image.jpg" with the actual URL of the image you want to download. Also, replace R.layout.activity_your and R.id.your_activity_layout with the appropriate layout ID for your activity and the ID of the layout you want to set the background to, respectively.

**Create a function to download the image**

```
suspend fun downloadImageFromUrl(context: Context, imageUrl: String): File? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
var file: File? = null
try {
    val url = URL(imageUrl)
    val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    connection.doInput = true
    connection.connect()
    val input: InputStream = connection.inputStream

    val outputDir = context.filesDir
    file = File.createTempFile("image", ".jpg", outputDir)
    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
    val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024) // 4KB buffer

    var bytesRead: Int
    while (input.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
    }

    outputStream.flush()
    outputStream.close()
    input.close()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
file
```

}

In your activity, use coroutines to download the image and set it as the background

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_your)

    val imageUrl = "https://www.example.com/image.jpg" // Replace with your image URL

    // Use a CoroutineScope to launch a coroutine
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val downloadedFile = downloadImageFromUrl(applicationContext, imageUrl)
        if (downloadedFile != null) {CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Mian).launch {
            onImageDownloaded(downloadedFile)}
        }
    }
}

private fun onImageDownloaded(imageFile: File) {
    val layout = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.your_activity_layout)
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.absolutePath)
    val drawable = BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)
    layout.background = drawable
}
```

}

Using coroutines, the image will be downloaded asynchronously without blocking the main thread, which can lead to a smoother user experience.